# Why aren't iframes working for certain sites

Tags: html, iframe

I was following a jQuery tutorial and part of it was to use something that took a long time to load, such as iframes. I can't get iframes to work by themselves, in the following only w3schools works. What is going on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello.</p>
    <p>

        <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> 
        <iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe> 
        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://www.reddit.com/"></iframe>
    </p>
    <p>Goodbye</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Are there any other easy ways to have something take a long time to load in a HTML document? I tried using large images but it's a nuisance to download many of them and they get cached after first time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209124/how-to-overcome-the-x-frame-options-in-iframe

Comment: These websites are preventing you from nesting them in your website for security reasons. As there is a inherent risk with a SSL based website being nested in a non-SSL environment.

Comment: @Celeritas There are almost more then you can count.

Comment: Blocking (i)frames is is about limiting copyright infringement and clickjacking.  Not everyone wants to i-frame for a "nice" reason.

Comment: It's also a number one cause of DOSing a server. If you don't use the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` I could then open your website on several networks millions of times and prevent anyone from using your website.

Comment: @bjb568 Denial of Service

Comment: DDoS (Distributed). "Denial of service" is the sign that McDonalds hang ("We reserve the right to deny service to anyone")

Comment: Haha you're funny. but anyway. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack That's like not calling a `<button>` a button because because before there were buttons to push, people wore them on shirts.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is, that Google/Satckoverflow is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. (You can set this thing either in IIS or in Page Header) This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

[The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)